# AWS CLI - How to filter returned DynamoDB items?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

The following command returns all items in a DynamoDB table.

`aws dynamodb scan --table-name TABLENAME`

How can I filter the items returns?  For example, my DynamoDB table has a property called `type`.  How can I filter the returned items such that the returned items are `type` = `somestring`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this with both Python and the AWS CLI tool. With the CLI tool you would add a Filter Expression using the `--filter-expression` command line option, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html).

With Python, it depends on which version of the AWS SDK you are using, either Boto or Boto3. I'm not going to dig into each of those, but you simply need to look up how to set a Filter Expression on a DynamoDB scan operation in your SDK of choice.